# Change value of a variable of the parent class in the child class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

```
class A {
    protected $a;

    // SOME CODE
}


class B extends A {
   // SOME CODE
}
```

How can i edit the protected value of the variable $a inside the B class ?

I'm trying to use `parent::$a = "Some Value"` but doesn't work.

Comment: Helpful, thank you hek2mgl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`protected` instance properties, those which where not declared using `static`, can be accessed in subclasses using `$this` :

```
class A {
    protected $a;

    // SOME CODE
}


class B extends A {
   // SOME CODE
   public function edit($val) {
       $this->$a = $val;
       echo "a is now {$this->a}\n";
   }
}
```

call:

```
$b = new B();
$b->edit('foo'); // a is now foo
```

Refer to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), especially the examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
class B extends A {    
  public function foo($val)
  {
    $this->a = $val;
  }
}
```

quite simple :)

Remember that

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes

from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)